# Access Query results with only multiple unique values

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have data that looks something like this:

```
P/N   Detail   Run Time
1001    1        1.0
1001    1        2.0
1001    2        1.5
1001    3        3.0
1002    1        1.0
1002    1        2.5
1003    1        1.0
1003    1        0.5
1004    1        1.2
1004    1        2.1
1004    2        3.5
```

I want to create a query or series of queries that removes the P/Ns associated with only one detail such that the results look like this:

```
P/N   Detail
1001    1
1001    2
1001    3
1004    1
1004    2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a Aggregate subquery, which ended up acting like a `SELECT DISTINCT`. The ultimate query ended up looking like:

```
SELECT [P/N+Det].[P/N], Count([P/N+Det].Detail) AS CountOfDetail
FROM [P/N+Det]
GROUP BY [P/N+Det].[P/N]
HAVING (((Count([P/N+Det].Detail))>1));
```

and the subquery looked like:

```
SELECT Hours.[P/N], Hours.Detail, Hours.Rev AS bomRev
FROM Hours
WHERE (((Hours.[Run Time])<>0))
GROUP BY Hours.[P/N], Hours.Detail, Hours.Rev;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```sql
SELECT [P/N], [Detail]
FROM [yourTable]
WHERE [P/N] IN
(
    SELECT [P/N]
    FROM [yourTable]
    GROUP BY [P/N]
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that each detail has multiple run times associated. So a P/N with 2 details can have up to 8 separate records and anything with a single detail will have a minimum of 2 records. I figured it out after tinkering for a couple hours and will post my results shortly.